Turn on/off flash on Sunmi L2s PRO
I need a way to turn off the flash of the Sunmi L2s PRO.
By "flash", I mean the light at the top of the device, next to the laser barcode scanner
(I do not mean the torch at the back of the device):

According to the Sunmi support, that is not possible. But the demo app which is shipped with the device has a setting which can enable or disable the flash, so there must be a way. But it seems like it is a private API.
Does anyone know how to toggle the flash or how I could reverse-engineer the demo app or "intercept" system calls etc. to find out how it is done?

The only two official methods to achieve what you want is by either pushing the setting from partner.sunmi.com web panel or through the scanner configuration (which you have called a demo) application.
As you correctly assume, there is a third - a bit more unofficial and not documented way - which I, as a person who already disassembled and reverse engineered the scanner service on Sunmi devices - discovered.
Just keep in mind that this is an unofficial API, that may stop working in the future. At this moment it works at every device I have tested (V2 Pro, V2s, V2s Plus, L2K, L2Ks, L2s and L2H), but it is not a guarantee.
To use it follow the steps:

Add the Sunmi scan head AIDL to your project according to Sunmi documentation.
To IScanInterface.aidl add the following line before closing curly bracket: void sendCommand(String str) = 5;
In your code (after you have bound the scanner service according to documentation) call the sendCommand with the parameter of either scan00000107=1; to enable or scan00000107=0; to disable flash control.

With this API you can change all options of scanner configuration. There is also a second private method to query for current scanner configuration. In the future I will publish everything what I have learned during reverse engineering scanner service in the form of a generic Android library, but until that will happen, you can refer to my capacitor.js plugin, where you could find the control codes for rest of the settings if you want.

Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

I made a small Android Java example project and it works. I can turn on/off the flash! May I ask how you found that out?

Sunmi hardware is great, software is not… On my V2Pro terminal was some bug, which prevented it from getting correct scanner configuration from Sunmi server. When I was trying to understand where it fails, I discovered how the configuration utility communicates with the scanner service. I dumped scanner service APK from all Sunmi devices I had, disassembled them and searched through them for all possible settings (there are few that I don’t know what they do) and here we are.

If you will have some other questions related to Sunmi terminals SDK’s, feel free to ask - as you can see, even Sunmi representatives were surprised what I found :)


Sunmi hardware is great, software is not…

I totally agree!
Thank you for your effort and sharing your findings!
